# Как получить из console.log(url) предыдущаю запись?

Tags: javascript

Дело в том, что я хочу сделать ссылку назад на страницу, а все переходы по XMLHttpRequest.
Подумал что можно вести лог и потом выводить предыдущую запись и кидать её в

> var par = document.querySelector('#nazad');   nazad.innerHTML = минус одна ссылка из лога

Тут берём

> console.log(url);

И делаем что то типо:

> console.log(url)(-1);

Подскажите как это реализовать. Спасибо!

Comment: А [Window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/history) Вам не подходит?

Comment: Нет. ajax погрузка страниц. Нет истории страниц.

Comment: Возможно не лучший вариант, но пишите в local storage, допустим последнюю страницу, ограничьтесь хранением необходимого количества страниц, остальные удаляйте постепенно

Comment: @Simon Да вариант, только как мне это сделать? Не смог реализовать из за дефицита знаний. Можете код показать, хотя бы пример на основании которого я смогу это сделать.

Comment: Если нужно хранить только последний URL, то можно просто делать `localStorage.setItem('lastURL', 'http://example.com');`, тем самым перезаписывая его в нужный момент чтобы он хранил только последний URL. Для вывода последнего URL используйте `localStorage.getItem('lastURL');`. Подробнее можно посмотреть в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Разобрался)